# rails nginx puma duplicate upstream "puma" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I've set up my server for this tutorial (https://coderwall.com/p/ttrhow/deploying-rails-app-using-nginx-puma-and-capistrano-3)

When I used one project, all works, but when I added another project to this VPS, I have error
`[emerg] 20737#0: duplicate upstream "puma" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vsejalreg:1`

My nginx's configure

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deployer/apps/vsejalreg/shared/tmp/sockets/vsejalreg-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name wjreg.rubyserv.ru www.wjreg.rubyserv.ru;

  root /home/deployer/apps/vsejalreg/current/public;
  access_log /home/deployer/apps/vsejalreg/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deployer/apps/vsejalreg/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

And

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deployer/apps/register/shared/tmp/sockets/register-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ws.rubyserv.ru www.ws.rubyserv.ru;

  root /home/deployer/apps/register/current/public;
  access_log /home/deployer/apps/register/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deployer/apps/register/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

When I add nginx configure one by one - all work!

How fix this bag or puma not working with many project?

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puma works with any proper configured project :) You can configure named upstream (upstream puma) just once, not with every server configuration. If you need different puma instances for each server, just setup upstreams with different names.

```
upstream puma_vsejalreg {
  server unix://...PATH.../vsejalreg-puma.sock;
}
upstream puma_register {
  server unix://...PATH.../register-puma.sock;
}
```

Comment: It's works! But, Need change http://puma to http://puma_vsejalreg; and http://puma_register Thx!

Comment: Yes, it is what I wrote - upstreams cant have duplicated names :) You need 1 upstream for all servers and you can name it "puma" for eхample OR you need 1 upstream per server and each upstream must be unique name (puma1, puma2, puma_register etc).

Comment: this each upstream is good for multi domain? example:  `foo.com` and `bar.com`

Answer (score 5):

Please note, that you need to change this part aswell:

```
location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }
```

Else you will run into errors such as this - `nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "puma" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/furnitureapp:25`

So, if you rename your upstream to

```
upstream puma_register
```

You need to rename your proxy_pass as well to

```
location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma_register; <------ Change here
  }
```