# Redirect from https to https doesn't work. Can't find server, ngnix

Tags: django, http, nginx, https, gunicorn

I tried to run site on https instead of http and therefore to create a redirect. At the moment site works at https adress. If I enter http adress, redirect to https takes place but it says it can't find server. What am I doing wrong? Commented is what I have also tried. I don't really understand why `server_name` is `_` in second configuration(which works), because it's a pre-installed image configuration on VPS

```
        upstream app_server {
        server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        #listen 80;
        #server_name solomon;
        #return 301 https://closer.com$request_uri;

        #server_name solomon;
        #listen 80;
        #return 301 https://closer.com;
    }

    server {
        #listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        listen 443;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/simple_academy_cert_chain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        client_max_body_size 4G;
        server_name _;

        keepalive_timeout 5;

        # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
        location /media  {
            alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
        }

  # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think You should  add your domain name in server_name. (i.e. server_name  example.com)

Comment: @GopalRoy I'v tried. Now tried one more time to add to 'server_name closer.com' didn't help

Comment: run: nginx -t
this prints any errors, just a reminder, restart the nginx service.

Comment: @MicroPyramid  sure I did. it's all ok

Comment: Could you show the exact error message?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides can't open that fact error message, because now dealing with this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169098/rails-nginx-puma-duplicate-upstream-puma-in-etc-nginx-sites-enabled

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I handle it on my server:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

All HTTP traffic gets redirected to HTTPS.